# Entering into password field using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

0
I am trying to do a tutorial and learn Selenium in python however i cant seem to get Selenium to enter the password into the password field/form box. It enters the email addres perfectly fine, and inside the code the password is typed correctly however the website returns it as "Incorrect password entered". However when i type the password in manually it logs in as it is correct. I have removed the email and password for security

I am using:

Python v3.9

Chrome v87

This is the URL i am practicing on:

https://www.aria.co.uk/myAria/ShoppingBasket?action=checkout

And this is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time

# Open Chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Ste1337\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

# Open webpage
driver.get("https://www.aria.co.uk/SuperSpecials/Other+products/ASUS+ROG+Pugio+2+Wireless+Optical+RGB+Gaming+Mouse?productId=72427")
#https://www.aria.co.uk/Products/Components/Graphics+Cards/NVIDIA+GeForce/GeForce+RTX+3060+Ti/Palit+GeForce+RTX+3060+Ti+Dual+8GB+GPU?productId=73054

# Click "Add to Basket" or refresh page if out of stock
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "Out of Stock!")))
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.refresh()
except:
    button = driver.find_element_by_id("addQuantityButton")
    button.click()

basket = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "basketContent")))
basket.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@src,'/static/images/checkoutv2.png')]"))).click()

login = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"login[email]")))
login.send_keys("testuser@hotmail.co.uk")
login.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
login.send_keys("password")
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
login.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined somewhere to put the password. Currently, the password in MEANT to be entered in the same place as the email. To change that, define where the password is meant to go. This is how I did it:

```py
passwrd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/h1/div[3]/div/div/input[2]")
passwrd.send_keys("password")
```

So in total, the code should look like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time

# Open Chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\eesam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver.exe")

# Open webpage
driver.get("https://www.aria.co.uk/SuperSpecials/Other+products/ASUS+ROG+Pugio+2+Wireless+Optical+RGB+Gaming+Mouse?productId=72427")
#https://www.aria.co.uk/Products/Components/Graphics+Cards/NVIDIA+GeForce/GeForce+RTX+3060+Ti/Palit+GeForce+RTX+3060+Ti+Dual+8GB+GPU?productId=73054

# Click "Add to Basket" or refresh page if out of stock
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "Out of Stock!")))
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.refresh()
except:
    button = driver.find_element_by_id("addQuantityButton")
    button.click()

basket = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "basketContent")))
basket.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@src,'/static/images/checkoutv2.png')]"))).click()

login = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"login[email]")))
login.send_keys("testuser@hotmail.co.uk")
login.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
passwrd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/h1/div[3]/div/div/input[2]")
passwrd.send_keys("password")
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
login.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```